# Does Leaflet support GeoTIFF ImageOverlay?

Tags: raster, leaflet, geotiff-tiff

I am planning to use Leaflet to display my raster images. I see the example usage in [ImageOverlay](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay) is using a `.jpg` format.

Would it also be possible if the image is GeoTIFF, `.tif` format?

I am just assuming that it is accepted since Earth Observation raster image is normally in GeoTIFF.

Comment: You may want to look at https://geotiffjs.github.io/

Comment: Leaflet can't display GeoTIFFs out of the box. Have a look at Leaflet plugins at https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html. There are several plugins that support GeoFIFF display.